# Is it possible to create multiple beans depending on prefix in application.properties in springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the following in my application.properties in my springboot application (1.5.4.RELEASE)

```
my.prefix.one.id=id01
my.prefix.one.name=one

my.prefix.two.id=id02
my.prefix.two.name=two
```

And a class like the following

```
public class MyClass{
 private String id;
 private String name;
 //getters and setters
}
```

If I use @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="my.prefix.one") then I get a MyClass bean with id field "id01".

Is there a way to indicate springboot to scan scan for all the properties with prefix "my.prefix" and create multiple beans. In this case two beans - bean with id field "id01" and bean with id field "id02" ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use springs `@ConfigurationProperties` and heve nested classes in your `MyClass`

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="my.prefix")
public class MyClass{

  private One id01;
  private Two id02;
  //GETTER SETTER

  public static class One {
    private String id;
    // GETTER SETTER
  }

  public static class Two {
    private String id;
    // GETTER SETTER
  }
}
```

Then you can access it like

```
myClass.getOne().getId();
```

Best thing for you to do is read through https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties

---

> Update: OP doen't want to use nested classes to retrieve those fields

```
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="my.prefix")
    public class MyClass{
      private String id01;
      private String id02;

      @NotNull
      private One one;
      @NotNull
      private Two two;

      public getId01(){
        return one.id;
      }
      public getId02(){
        return two.id;
      }

      public static class One {
        private String id;
        // GETTER SETTER
      }

      public static class Two {
        private String id;
        // GETTER SETTER
      }
    }
```

and now you can use them like

```
   myClass.getId01();
   myClass.getId02();
```

Comment: but I don't want to create two class definitions MyClass.One and MyClass.Two. They both have the same structure

Comment: Having same structure should not be a problem. I have modified the myClass getters to match your requirement. Hope you wanted to use it like this. are you ?

Comment: He was not concerned if they have same structure, he did not want to create one class per instance.

Comment: @pavankumar i am still awaiting OP to confirm by answering my question.

Comment: @Amit, what are your thoughts on answer I just proposed? i.e., using multiple configuration methods instead of multiple nested classes.

Comment: This is not the structure which the user asked for.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to do similar and as far as I am aware the only way to create multiple instances is to to get *all* properties with a specified prefix and parse them yourself. For your example you could construct a `@Configuration` like so:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my.prefix")
    protected Map<String, String> myProperties() {
        return new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Bean
    public List<MyClass> myObjects(@Qualifier("myProperties") final Map<String, String> myProperties) {

        final Map<String, Map<String, String>> mappedSources = new HashMap<>();
        myProperties.forEach((key1, value) -> {
            final String[] key = key1.split("\\.");
            final Map<String, String> myInstanceParams = mappedSources.computeIfAbsent(key[0], s -> new HashMap<>(2));
            myInstanceParams.put(key[1], value);
        });
        return mappedSources.values().stream()
                .map(stringStringMap -> new MyClass(stringStringMap.get("id"), stringStringMap.get("name")))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

In this simple instance the `@Qualifier` is not needed in `myObjects()` parameter list but if you introduce a second prefix where you want to do similar then you need to qualify which map of strings is to be passed into the `myObjects()` method so I would recommend just including it from the start.

This is a simple example but a more robust implementation would check for missing properties and property validity etc. Nor can I say if this solution is good practice/good Spring practice.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using springboot, you can also do:

```
@Configuration
public class AppBeanConfig {
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="my.prefix.one")  
    public MyClass myClassOne(){
      return new MyClass();
   }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="my.prefix.two")  
    public MyClass myClassTwo(){
      return new MyClass();
   }
}
```

I am not aware of any meaningfull ways to avoid configuring individual beans.

However, if that what you really want to do, you can gain access to ApplicationContext and manually process the properties and inject beans to Applicationcontext, personally I would prefer add multiple bean methods to configuration class than directly manipulating ApplicationContext.

Comment: What is the problem with above solution? Can you refer me to simpler solution then this? I don't think having inner strategic class and two instance in the parent for is better than having two break methods.

Answer (score -1):

If the properties for one, two are the same, simply use the same class. Lombok helps you to auto-create getter/setter methods, which are required in order to make it worke

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="my.prefix")
public class MyClass {

  private Child one;
  private Child two;

  @Getter
  @Setter
  public static class Child {

    @NotNull
    private String id;
    @NotNull
    private String name;
  }
}
```

Comment: You can create two beans with beach methods annotated correctly than creating nested static class.